# Access HTTP header for swagger generated client exception

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a project in C# that is using a REST client generated by swagger. When the server sends an error HTTP status code 429 for example this generated client throws `ApiException`. I would like to access the headers from the HTTP response as I'm interested in the `Retry-After` header.

I did not see any helpfull members on the `ApiException` type and I can't find any API documentation for runtime classes used by this generated client.

Comment: *generated by swagger* - Swagger is a specification. What tool generated the client? Autorest? NSwag? etc..

Comment: @CaiusJard Swagger Codegen

Comment: Not one I've used, but if it works in the same way as all the others it'll build a big block of c# that implements  the client - you should be able to find it somewhere in the project folders and read it. Often these generators leave obvious hooks in, like making all the classes partial or providing some command line option to specify a base class that they shall all inherit from, then you write the base class and it exposes whatever you want. If you don't get any joy from codegen, take a look at another generator : I know nswag allows the level of customzation you're after..